# Recursive calls when trying to wrap and override the global operator new

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I have not programmed C++ for a while and encountered a strange behavior when toying with overloaded global operators `new` and `delete`.
The essence of the problem seems to be that a wrapper build around the default global `new` and residing in a *separate* source file 
nevertheless calls an `operator new`  overloaded in another (and separately compiled so) source file.

Why is it so, i.e. which language rules / features am I violating / misusing?

Thanks in advance, the details are below.

Project structure:

```
.
..
main.cpp
mem_wrappers.h
mem_wrappers.cpp
```

Project files contents:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "./mem_wrappers.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


void* operator new[] (size_t sz) throw (std::bad_alloc) {
  std::cout << "overloaded new()[]" << std::endl;
    return default_arr_new_wrapper(sz);
}


int main() {
    const unsigned num = 5;
    int * i_arr = new int [num];

    return 0;
}
```

**mem_wrappers.h**

```
#include <cstring>


void * default_arr_new_wrapper(size_t sz);
```

**mem_wrappers.cpp**

```
#include <new>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>


void * default_arr_new_wrapper(size_t sz) {
    std::cout << "default_arr_new wrapper()" << std::endl;
    return ::operator new[](sz);
}
```

Complied with *g++ main.cpp mem_wrappers.cpp --ansi --pedantic -Wall* when run gives endless `operator new[]` to `default_arr_new_wrapper` and vice versa calls resulting in the following output:

```
overloaded new()[]

default_arr_new_wrapper()

overloaded new()[]

default_arr_new_wrapper()

...
```

and, finally, in SO (the MS Visual Studio Express compiler behaves alike).

Compilers I use: **gcc version 3.4.2 (mingw-special)** and **MS Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.1 SP**.

EDIT / UPDATE

If (as the first answers and comments suggest) the global `operator new` is effectively redefined for the whole executable just by overloading it [the operator] in a single compilation unit, then:

is it that merely linking with an object file whose source overloads the global `operator new` makes any application or library change its (well, lets  call it so) memory allocation policy? Is thus this overload operator efficiently providing a hook for the language runtime (I mean what's with those linker symbols in the already-compiled-without-any-overloaded-new object files, is it that there can be only one `new`)?

P.S. I know that `malloc`  and `free` would do, and already tried them before posting here (worked ok), but nevertheless, what's behind this behavior (and what if I was actually to wrap the default `operator new` anyway? :)) ?

Comment: As its name suggests, global operator new is global.

Comment: @Neil And what about the linkage (isn't it global to the current compilation unit)?

Comment: mlvljr, you can place a \ (backslash) in front of your underscores to avoid rendering the following characters in italics.  But generally, when you refer to a variable name it's preferable to render it as code, like `varname`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read the wording in the standard, what you do to global `operator new` function when you define your own is called *replacement* (not *overloading* and not *overriding*). Most of the time when people talk about changing the global `operator new` functionality they use the term "overloading" and refer to `new` as an "operator". This often leads to confusion, when the resultant behavior does not agree with what is normally expected from *operator overloading*. This is apparently what happens in your case. You expect *overloading* behavior, but what you really get is *replacement*: once you defined one replacement version of global `operator new` function in some translation unit it works for the entire program. (And `new` is not really an operator.)

As a side note, *replacement* is one of those rare "unfair" language features, in a sense that it is not generally available to the user. You can't write "replaceable" functions in C++. You can't write anything that would behave the way default library implementations of global `operator new` and `operator new` behave. (Replacement is a language-level manifestation of the linker concept of a *weak symbol*).

Comment: Accepting this one as adding really much to Neil's comment :))

Comment: but why did gcc allow overriding the operator new with the same signature in global namespace? VS does not allow (linker gives error telling that the name is already defined).

Comment: @Chubsdad: I don't understand what you are talking about. Both GCC and MSVC allow replacement of the global `operator new`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's much to add after Neil's comment but if you overload global operator new, you can't do it for just one translation unit, `new` will be overloaded for the entire executable or dll.

As you've noticed calling global operator new from within your own overloaded global operator new you will get endless recursion (well, until you run out of stack space at least ;)

If you want to toy around with this try using `malloc` and `free` inside your wrapper to get up and running.

If the operators were only local to one translation unit you would run into trouble if you passed an object which were allocated with one version of `new` to another translation unit and tried to delete it with another, non matching, operator `delete`.

The details of operator `new` and `delete` are covered in section 18.4 of the C++ standard.

Comment: So, it is global in a different way than, say, global variables, right? Where can I read the rules (and probably rationale) for this (i.e. the standard, "The C++ programming language" book)?

Comment: P.S. Malloc and free worked fine, its this strange behavior I'm dazzled with.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Neil's comment, "global" new may not be given the `static` storage class specifier, and is therefore "global" - it is visible to the linker outside of the module (could be extern'd from any other module, for instance).

Invalid:

```
static void* operator new(size_t sz) {}
```

Valid:

```
//in main.cpp
void* operator new(size_t sz) {}

//in foo.cpp
extern void* operator new(size_t sz);
```

Depending on what you want to do, the best approach can be to use malloc/new in your definitions, or add a parameter to your override so the signature changes (you can then fall-back to the default global new without recursion).

Don't forget about throwing an exception in case of allocation failure, and implementing no-throw versions of your overloads.

Comment: Aha! So different compilation units cannot rely on `new` operators of their own then..

Comment: Anything declared in a module that is not static is visible to the linker from outside the module. This is essentially the purpose of "extern" - to tell the compiler "this var/func/etc is declared in another module". It's good practice to make anything you don't expect to be referenced from outside the module (source file) static , but this is not allowed in the case of operator new.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d(VS.80).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd(VS.80).aspx for reminder of extern & static.

Answer (score 1):

To amplify what AndreyT has said:

When you write your own global `operator new` function you provide a definition that the linker can see.  When it comes to link time, the linker will need to find a definition for `new`, just because its used a lot.  It starts searching in the object files that you are asking it to link, and hey-presto there it is, so it can stop searching.

If you had not provided a definition, it would have carried on searching through any other object files of yours, then through libraries you provide, and finally through the run-time that comes with your compiler, which has to provide one or nothing would link.

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the GNU C++ standard lib, you see decorations like this one, meaning "weak linking":

```
_GLIBCXX_WEAK_DEFINITION void *
operator new (std::size_t sz) throw (std::bad_alloc)
```